# header Location is not taking the declared path

Tags: php

Im trying to kill a session if array's keys of $_SESSION is empty, then redirecting to a script whose destroys the session and redirect to index. This is my files structure

```
backend
  apis
    profiles
      search.php
  core
    session_end.php
    CoreTools.php
frontend
index.php
landing.php
```

This is the `CoreTools.php` code

```
class CoreTools{

  protected $session;
  public function __construct( $inSession ){
      $this->session = $inSession;
  }


  public function sessionLost(){

    $return = false;
    if( empty( $this->session ) ){
      $return = true;

    }else{
      foreach( $this->session as $s ){
          if( empty( $s ) ){$return = true;}
      }
    }


    return $return;
  }

  public function checkPermissions( $perm ){
    if( self::sessionLost() ){
     header('Location: session_end.php');

    }else{
      //too much code
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Above code is called by `search.php`

```
session_start();
require '../../core/CoreTools.php';
$_SESSION = null;
$tools = new CoreTools( $_SESSION );
if( !$tools->checkPermissions( 'get' ) ){
    $response['success'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'Not allowed';

  }else{


  }
```

I'm setting `$_SESSION = null` intentionally to test the code

`search.php` is called by `landing.php` via AJAX

I got 404 error

If I use

```
header('Location: session_end.php');
```

The server responses

> Not Found The requested URL /backend/apis/profiles/session_end.php was
>   not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Looks like the it is searching the `session_end.php` file inside profiles folder, why? `CoreTools.php` is inside core folder besides `session_end.php`

I Tried as this way too

```
header('Location: http://www.mysite.tv/backend/core/session_end.php');
```

And it returns a CORS error ( I don´t want to configure CORS now )

As this way too

```
$path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/backend/core/session_end.php';
header('Location: ' . $path);
```

This is the 404 error

> Not Found The requested URL
>   /backend/apis/profiles/http//www.mysite.tv/backend/core/session_end.php
>   was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

And this is desesperated solution

```
echo '<script>window.location.href="./backend/core/session_end.php"</script>';
```

And it doesn´t work

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I usually use a lowercase l and put a line feed at the end, but do you say ajax, so ajax won't follow the redirection, you will need to do that in the javascript

Comment: @DavidBray case is not significant in header names, and you shouldn't add a newline.

Comment: Don't forget the `exit`!

Comment: Looks like the _current_ URL path is `/backend/apis/profile/search.php` so if you want to redirect from that to `session_end.php`, you would use either the absolute path `/backend/core/session_end.php` or relative path `../../core/session_end.php`

Comment: @phil, if I do that, maybe when I use `CoreTools()` from core folder it won´t work. Why the relative path is not working? Dharman, i tried too and it returns the first error.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, sorry. It should not be an issue if you use absolute paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative URLs are processed by the client, not the server. The client interprets it relative to the URL that it loaded, which is in the `profiles` folder, so that's where it looks for `session_end.php`.

There's not much point in redirecting an AJAX call, since AJAX doesn't reload the page on the client.

The CORS error is probably caused by the original AJAX call using `https:`, but you're redirecting to `http:`, which is considered a different domain. You can leave out the protocol and domain in the URL and it will inherit them from the original URL.

```
header('Location: /backend/core/session_end.php');
```